# Calculations in CUBE with Dimension at row level

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have a situation can someone help me with my problem. I have a **SSAS Cube** in which I need to calculate with Dimensional table on row basis. Following is the scenario..

I have a Dimensional & Fact tables as follows:

**Dimensional Table:**

[image]

**Fact Table:**

[image]

Now I need to add two calculations:

One as 'Metric6' as Metric & 'MG3' as corresponding MetricGroup in Dimensional Table and ( MetricValue = Metric1 + Metric2 ) as corresponding MetricValue in Fact Table.

The second calculation will be as 'Metric7' as Metric & 'MG4' as corresponding MetricGroup in Dimensional Table and ( MetricValue = Metric4 / Metric 5 ) as corresponding MetricValue in Fact Table.

I Know we can do this calculations in SQL itself, but I need to do this in the Cube dynamically.

Comment: Thank you Kanchit for the edit!

Comment: How are your fact and dim tables related?

Comment: They are related with a Foreign Key relation on MetricID

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't provide this information. Could you please upload full data scheme and sql code that gives you wished result.

Comment: There are lot more dimension tables. I just created a sample of my scenario for your understanding. Actually The Metric Dimensional Table have MetricID, MetricGroup, Metric as Columns, The Fact table have MetricID, MetricValue as Columns. MetricID of Fact table is in Foreign Key  relationship with MetricId of Dimensional table. I just need to create calculations based on this two table in the Cube.

Comment: Okay, last questions: Do you have MetricGroup and Metric attributes in your cube? Your sql formula: iif(Metric = 'Metric6' and MetricGroup = 'MG3', MetricValue, null), right?

Comment: Yes, I have the MetricGroup and Metric attributes in the Cube. They are not calculated, they come directly from corresponding Dimensional table attributes.

Comment: Please can you add the equivalent `sql` code. Also please can you post a small table showing an example of the resulting table you're hoping to achieve? Currently this question is vague and will get marked down or people will vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure, but probably you need:

```
Member [Measures].[TheFirst] as
IIF(
    [Metric].[Metric].CurrentMember is [Metric].[Metric].&[Metric6]
    and
    [Metric].[MetricGroup].CurrentMember is [Metric].[MetricGroup].&[MG3],
    [Measures].[MetricValue],
    NULL
)


Member [Measures].[TheSecond] as
IIF(
    [Metric].[Metric].CurrentMember is [Metric].[Metric].&[Metric7]
    and
    [Metric].[MetricGroup].CurrentMember is [Metric].[MetricGroup].&[MG4],
    [Measures].[MetricValue],
    NULL
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, But I do not understand how can we get MG4 in MetricGroup as we do not have MG4 in the Dimensional table and how do we calculate corresponding MetricValues with out adding new calculated member , I have to display these calculation in MetricValue column itself. Thank you again for the reply.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you wish to achieve. Could you please post the SQL code and the corresponding output to your question? Then, I'll translate it into MDX, if possible.